# Iterate over a type without instantiating it

Tags: python, class, iterator, static-methods, magic-methods

## Problem

I want to be able to iterate over a type without instantiating it, similar to an enum.

```py
class Foo:
    """Class I want to iterate over without instantiating."""
    ALLOWED_VALUES = (1, 2, 3)

# I want iterating over `Foo` to be equivalent to iterating over `Foo.ALLOWED_VALUES`
for val_from_tuple, val_from_foo in zip(Foo.ALLOWED_VALUES, Foo):
    assert val_from_tuple == val_from_foo
```

This behaviour is possible with an enum, but only if `ALLOWED_VALUES` are valid python names. I want to have the same iteration behaviour without this restriction.

## What I tried

I tried implementing `__iter__()` as a `staticmethod` on `Foo` so that an instance of `Foo` wouldn't be needed to get an `Iterator` for it. This allows me to iterate over `Foo.__iter__()`, but `iter(Foo)` raises an error. This seems to be because `iter(Foo)` looks for an `__iter__` method on `type`, not on `Foo` (since `Foo` is a `type` object).

```py
class Foo:
    """Class I want to iterate over without instantiating."""
    ALLOWED_VALUES = (1, 2, 3)

    @staticmethod
    def __iter__():
        return Foo.ALLOWED_VALUES

# This works, but isn't what I want because it involves calling `__iter__()` explicitly.
for val in Foo.__iter__():
    print(val)

# This raises an error:
# `TypeError: 'type' object is not iterable`
for val in Foo:
    print(val)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Enum` is iterable because it uses a different metaclass (`EnumMeta` rather than `type`) to create it. You can define your own metaclass to provide a definition of `__iter__` which `type` itself lacks.

```
class IterableClass(type):
    def __iter__(self):
        yield from self.ALLOWED_VALUES

class Foo(metaclass=IterableClass):
    ALLOWED_VALUES = (1,2,3)

for x, y in zip(Foo.ALLOWED_VALUES, Foo):
    assert x == y
```

Comment: A minor nitpick: consider naming the `self` parameter `cls` in a metaclass method, to remind the reader that it's dealing with a class object.

Comment: I go back and forth on that. It's still possible to define class methods in a metaclass, so I usually feel it's better to simply remember than an instance of a metaclass is a class.

Comment: (One could use `cls`/`metacls` in place of `self`/`cls`, though.)